# Rails 3 with Devise and IE cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, devise, session-cookies

I have a Rails 3 app running on Heroku. For authentication I use devise. The session data are stored in a cookie.

Now when I use Firefox I can see the cookie - I use a Firefox plugin to see it; when I use IE I cannot see it: there is not cookie file getting set and when I use the developer console to view the cookies I get nothing. The web app is working fine in IE so somehow the cookie gets sent to the server.

What is going on? How can I see the session cookie in IE?

Thanks for any help.
-Matteo

Answer (score 2):

Does your URL contain an underscore? Internet Explorer does not like underscores in the URL when handling cookies.

Comment: IE only rejects cookies if the domain, hostname or subdomain containers underscores. The questioner is running on Heroku, which shouldn't allow this anyway, so that's probably not the issue here.